# background image rendering on tablet is slow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just had an issue with a static site I have to build. I have a simple site which is about 6000px tall (that's a lot of scrolling!) and have a lot of images. I made these images to be a `background-image` in CSS becouse this site has to use parallax scroll. I use the [stellar.js](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/) lib. to achieve this.

My problem is that everything is working fine on desktop, but on tablet, when the user starts to scroll down, she/he can saw the rendering process of that image which is on the viewport at the moment. (the user saw a white space on the page).

After the user scrolled the whole page, some images rendering again. I resized all the images and made them as small as possible (they all together 1.2 mb), but the users saw the same rendering process. Is there a way to achieve to prevent the user to see the rendering process? (maybe it is not the rendering process).
P.S.: Right now i can't give you the code. Sorry!

Comment: Do you know it it's the images rendering, or the images loading (i.e. being downloaded from the server?) You should be able to check using chrome dev tools (simulate a slow connection, and see if the same behavior occurs)

Comment: @Kyle Fahringer after some researching i found that the browser repaint it. The image is loaded in the DOM but after every scroll event, the browser allways repaint it.